# Changing content of variable using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, sitecore-mvc

I am currently working with an Sitecore MVC project, in which i have some problems understanding how I can alter my model, which currently consist two of a `string tech` and `string add` dynamically using jQuery.

My idea was to have the index file like this

```
var global_var1 = "";
var global_var2 = "";

<div class = "upper">
    <div class= "tech_field" >
    @Model.tech = global_var1
    </div>
    <div class= "add_field" >
    @Model.add = global_var2
    </div>
</div>
```

And then with the jQuery do something like

```
$('upper').find('tech_field')
```

But how do i exactly modify the value or the variable, i know how to find the `div` which contains the value, but not the exact variable.

Comment: it's a class! `.` so use that `.` like `$('.upper').find('.tech_field') ` There's a huge difference between `upper`=`<upper>` and `.upper`=`<div class="upper">`

Comment: I want to change `@Model.tech` variable,  how does that alter the variable..

Answer (score 0):

`@Model` is a variable defined only on the server-side when the page is generated. On the client side in the browser, you do not have access to server-side variables.

`@Model.tech` renders the tech property value at that location in the page.

So this code:

```
<div class= "tech_field" >
@Model.tech = global_var1
</div>
```

Will render this if `@Model.tech` contains "Content of the tech property":

```
<div class= "tech_field" >
Content of the tech property = global_var1
</div>
```

If you want to use JavaScript to render your model property values, you can do it like this:

```
<script>
    // Sets JavaScript variables with the content of server-side model property values
    var model_tech = "@Model.tech";
    var model_add = "@Model.add";
</script>

<div class="upper">
    <div class="tech_field"></div>
    <div class="add_field"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.tech_field').text(model_tech); // Sets the DOM element value to the content of the JavaScript variable
    var techValueFromDom = $('.tech_field').text(); // Reads the DOM to read the text.
</script>
```

However, there is no easy way to call Sitecore to update data stored in Sitecore items from JavaScript code.